Deriving the big $O_p$ of a sum involving estimation errors of bounded functions
Suppose $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\{f(X_i) - \hat{f}_n(X_i)\}^2$ and $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\{g(X_i) - \hat{g}_n(X_i)\}^2$ are $O_p(a^2_n)$ for some sequence $a_n$ such that $a_n = O(n^{-r}$) where $r > 1/4$.
Suppose $Y_i$ is a binary 0/1 random variable, $f(\cdot)$ is bounded between -1 and 1, (i.e., $-1 \leq f(X_i) \leq 1$ for any $X_i$) and $g(\cdot)$ is bounded between 0 and 1 (i.e., $0 \leq g(X_i) \leq 1$ for any $X_i$). Observations $i = 1, \ldots, n$ are i.i.d, and $\hat{f}_n(\cdot)$ and $\hat{g}_n(\cdot)$ are estimators obtained from these observations.
What is the big $O_p$ for
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n [(f(X_i) - \hat{f}_n(X_i))g(X_i) + (\hat{f}_n(X_i) - Y_i)(g(X_i) - \hat{g}_n(X_i))]^2?$$
Expanding the square, we get a sum of 3 terms:
\begin{align*}
&\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n [(f(X_i) - \hat{f}_n(X_i))g(X_i) + (\hat{f}_n(X_i) - Y_i)(g(X_i) - \hat{g}_n(X_i))]^2\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \{f(X_i) - \hat{f}_n(X_i)\}^2g^2(X_i)+2(f(X_i) - \hat{f}_n(X_i))g(X_i)(\hat{f}_n(X_i) - Y_i)(g(X_i) - \hat{g}_n(X_i)) + (\hat{f}_n(X_i) - Y_i)^2(g(X_i) - \hat{g}_n(X_i))^2
\end{align*}
Term 1: $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \{f(X_i) - \hat{f}_n(X_i)\}^2g^2(X_i)$
Since $g(X_i)$ is bounded, and $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\{f(X_i)-\hat{f}_n(X_i)\}^2$ is $O_p(a^2_n)$, then Term 1 is $O_p(a^2_n)$.
Term 2: $\frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (f(X_i) - \hat{f}_n(X_i))g(X_i)(\hat{f}_n(X_i) - Y_i)(g(X_i) - \hat{g}_n(X_i))$
Since $g(X_i) \leq 1$ and $|\hat{f}_n(X_i) - Y_i| \leq 2$, then we have
\begin{align*}
&\frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (f(X_i) - \hat{f}_n(X_i))g(X_i)(\hat{f}_n(X_i) - Y_i)(g(X_i) - \hat{g}_n(X_i))\\ &\leq C \sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \{f(X_i)-\hat{f}_n(X_i)\}^2\right)\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \{g(X_i) - \hat{g}_n(X_i)\}^2\right)}\\
&= O_p(a^2_n)
\end{align*}
where $C$ is some positive constant, and the inequality holds by Cauchy-Schwarz.
Term 3: $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (\hat{f}_n(X_i) - Y_i)^2(g(X_i) - \hat{g}_n(X_i))^2$
Since $|\hat{f}_n(X_i) - Y_i| \leq 2$
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (\hat{f}_n(X_i) - Y_i)^2(g(X_i) - \hat{g}_n(X_i))^2 \leq \frac{4}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (g(X_i) - \hat{g}_n(X_i))^2 = O_p(a^2_n)$$
Altogether, we have
\begin{align*}
&\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n [(f(X_i) - \hat{f}_n(X_i))g(X_i) + (\hat{f}_n(X_i) - Y_i)(g(X_i) - \hat{g}_n(X_i))]^2\\ &= O_p(a^2_n) + O_p(a^2_n) + O_p(a^2_n)\\
&= O_p(a^2_n)
\end{align*}
Is the above correct? I'm not very sure about Term 2 and Term 3 particularly with respect to factoring out $\hat{f}_n(X_i)-Y_i$.

Did you try to simulate it?

@Adrian the example was actually incorrect. That expectation $e^{-n}/n$ only decreases faster than $e^{-n} \cdot e^{-n(1-p)}$ when $p=1$. If the variable is non-negative, then for any quantile $p<1$ the decrease is bounded by the decrease of the expectation.

The expressions are not all clear. Subscripts are missing occasionally. Also, the bounds of $\hat{f}(X_n)$ are not clear.

"Assume observations i=1,…,n
are i.i.d" Does this mean that the terms ${f(X_i) - \hat{f}(X_i)}$ are i.i.d. distributed? Then, if the average of their square approaches zero, this must mean that the expectation of the square is zero and that these variables have a zero second raw moment $E[{f(X_i) - \hat{f}(X_i)}^2] = 0$.

No. ${f(X_i) - \hat{f}(X_i)}$ is not necessarily i.i.d. because I'll clarify that $\hat{f}$ is an estimator derived from ${X_i}_{i=1}^n$.

Are the $X_i$ i.i.d.?

Yes, $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are i.i.d.

@Adrian, but if $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are i.i.d. then functions of them are also i.i.d. Or is the function $\hat{f}(\cdot)$ not the same in the terms of the summation? That doesn't make my earlier comment working, or... we do still have $E[{f(X_i) - \hat{f}(X_i)}^2] = 0$ but only in the limit $n \to \infty$. It would be easier to clarify by adding a subscript like $\hat{f}_n$.

I'll modify clarify in the post that $\hat{f}$ is a function of all the data points by adding a subscript $\hat{f}_n$. Thanks.

In theory no, in practice yes.
Since $f(\cdot)$ is bounded between 1 and -1, any sensible estimator $\hat{f}_n(\cdot)$ would alo be bounded between 1 and -1. In that case, we can bound $|g(X_i)| \leq 1$ and $|\hat{f}_n(X_i) - Y_i| \leq 2$ and everything works.
$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \left[(f(X_i) - \hat{f}_n(X_i))g(X_i) + (\hat{f}_n(X_i) - Y_i)(g(X_i) - \hat{g}_n(X_i))\right]^2 \\
\leq \frac{4}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \left[|f(X_i) - \hat{f}_n(X_i)| + |g(X_i) - \hat{g}_n(X_i)|\right]^2\\
\leq \frac{8}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \left[|f(X_i) - \hat{f}_n(X_i)|^2 + |g(X_i) - \hat{g}_n(X_i)|^2\right]\\
= 8\cdot O_p(a_n^2) + 8\cdot O_p(a_n^2) = O_p(a_n^2)\\
\end{align}$$
However, if we have some crazy estimator, things may go wrong. Consider for example the following scenario:

$f(X_i) = g(X_i) = 0$ for all $i$
$\hat{f}_n(X_i) = \hat{g}_n(X_i) = \sqrt[5]{n}$ if $n = 32^k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$
$\hat{f}_n(X_i) = \hat{g}_n(X_i) = 0$ if $n$ is not a power of 32

In this case $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (f(X_i) - \hat{f}_n(X_i))^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (g(X_i) - \hat{g}_n(X_i))^2 = O(n^{-3/5})$.
However, setting $n = 32^k$, we also get
$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \left[(f(X_i) - \hat{f}_n(X_i))g(X_i) + (\hat{f}_n(X_i) - Y_i)(g(X_i) - \hat{g}_n(X_i))\right]^2\\
= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{k} \left[2^i\cdot g(X_{32^i}) + (2^i - Y_{32^i})(g(X_{32^i}) - 2^i)\right]^2\\
\geq \frac{1}{n}\left[n^{1/5}\cdot g(X_n) + (n^{1/5} - Y_n)(g(X_n) - n^{1/5})\right]^2\\ = \Omega(n^{-1/5})\\
\end{align}$$
which contradicts that the expression would be $O_p(a_n^2)$ for some $a_n = O(n^{-r})$ with $r > 1/4$.
